# Calculate area in square meter of a polygon using php or/and mysql

Tags: mysql, geometry

I use the ST_AREA to get the polygon surface in mysql but i missed something because the result seems incorrect.

This is the query :

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_PolyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON(((2.2498939 50.7500442,2.2500789 50.7500817,2.250089 50.7500838,2.2500375 50.7501895,2.2498874 50.7501631,2.2498701 50.7501374,2.2498939 50.7500442)))')) AS area
```

This is the result :
0.00000002145686295307314

This is the reality :
[image]

So from here, how can i get the result in m2 or km2 ?

Comment: No 2.25 is the longitude and 50.75 the latitude

Comment: *This is the result : 0.00000002145686295307314* - this is 21.4 sq.m, it seems.

Comment: I want to be sure indeed, but 21,4 sq.m seems too small regarding the building size

Comment: Oops, sorry, 214 m2. ~15*15m... For 4326 the value must be multiplied with 10000 for to obtain the length in meters, so 10 000 000 for a squares.